# IronPython Linting Tool

Tags: python, ironpython, pylint, flake8

I have looked into a couple of linting tools so far as flake8 and pylint would both be great. Unfortunately, I need to use these linting tools with IronPython instead of CPython. How do I go about using pylint (or alternatively flake8) with IronPython?

Answer (score 0):

I believe IronPython has the exact same syntax as CPython (or any other Python implementation) so Flake8 and pylint should Just Work. You'll need to install them and both packages strongly suggest using pip. I've not used IronPython before so you should install pip into your IronPython environment and then use that to install Flake8 and PyLint. (You can and should use both. They're complimentary, not mutually exclusive. In fact, Flake8 uses PyLint in addition to itself.)

Comment: Well the problem isn't installing the linting tool. I imagine pylint is configured only to detect Python code so it flags all the C# code as unrecognized/invalid. Is there a workaround for this?